# Application deployed on tomcat stopped responding

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

The web application deployed on tomcat stopped responding when 1K requests hit the server. While looking at catalina.out logs , the last 100+ lines are :

Finalizer, called close()

Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)

Finalizer, called close()

Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)

Is this because of memory issue?

Comment: you should have looked at the entire logs, there must be a cause logged there as well

Comment: There is no such error..The only thing i could see after scrolling a couple of line up is a successful handshake.

Comment: can you share your server.xml configuration file as well in that case

Comment: any specific info that i must look?

Comment: `maxConnections` I would say

Comment: This is not explicitly specified, i guess default 200 is being used

Comment: In that case you shouldn't have reached 1K ever. Could possibly be 1K as default I believe.

Comment: try to look dumps (heap, crash), not only logs

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat was configured to use 200 Worker threads. In my application code, I was putting some data  in to a blocking queue which was full. So Threads started blocking in order to wait for room in the BlockingQueue. One by one all 200 Threads were blocked and Hence the requests were not being served. I changed the blocking call to Time bounded wait. 
Finally got rid of the issue.

Comment: I faced similar issue , and resolution was somewhat similar as above